# Why gettext translate in PHP file not working?

Tags: php, gettext, poedit

I don't understand what I do wrong. Maybe someone help me. I just trying to follow the instructions, but translate not working.

This is phpinfo(); file: https://equipe.viacast.eu/phpinfo.php

[gettext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGqUK.png)
[mbstring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Bio.png)

Next I did this:

new file: translate.php

```
<?php echo  _("Good Morning"); ?>
```

In command line I use this line which does create the .po files directly from the

```
xgettext -n translate.php
```

After that if messages.po file will be generated I edit language and the charset line.

```
"Language fr\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
```

Now I add this lines in .PO file:

```
#: translate.php:2
  msgid "Good Morning"
  msgstr "Bonjour"
```

After that I open command line and type this line

```
msgfmt messages.po
```

I create next folders:

```
locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES
```

and I moved messages.mo and messages.po in this folder:

```
locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES
```

Next I edit the translate.php file and I added next lines:

```
<?php

 $locale = "fr_FR";

    if (defined('LC_MESSAGES')) {
        setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale); // Linux
        bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
    } else {
        putenv("LC_ALL={$locale}"); // windows
        bindtextdomain("messages", ".\locale");
    }

    
    textdomain("messages");

    echo _("Good Morning");
?>
```

After that I open translate.php file in browser and the text has not changed. Still showing "Good Morning" text when it should show "Bonjour"

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows? Why do you not call `setlocale()` on Windows? And try an absolute path instead of `./locale` unless you know what the current working directory is.

Comment: I’m using Linux Ubuntu Server 20.04 VPS

Comment: And did you try an absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"Language: fr\n"
```

instead of

```
"Language fr\n"
```

;-)

And this can also help if you are going to use plural forms:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"
```